# How to clear task stack when another activity is started from another app

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

An activity (DBRestoreActivity) is started via a received intent in response to the user "View"ing an email attachment or sending a file to the activity from a file chooser.

When this activity is started, I'd like the task stack (if it already exists) to be cleared. My app is not starting the activity. It is being started via receipt of the Action.View Intent from another app.

Notice that I have set launchMode-singleTask. Without this setting, the DBRestoreActivity opens in its own task. I thought if I could get it into the same task as the currently running activity (if any) that I would be able to close the current activity or clear the current task's stack.

I did set the DBRestoreActivity clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in the AndroidManifest, hoping it would close all but the root activity. But It did not do this.

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/appName" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ball"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DBRestoreActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activityDB_restore"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/appName" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mydomain.myapp.activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm posting an answer to my own question....

So, the DBRestoreActivity above is being "instantiated" via a received intent with action View. My app is not instantiating the activity.

I understand (although an Android newbie) that if we can set the Intent flags: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK on the DBRestoreActivity, I would get the desired state: the DBRestoreActivity would start a new task (if one doesn't already exist) or clear the existing task state and add the activity to the existing task.

The way I solved this was to create another activity, DBRestoreLoaderActivity.  This activity is now specified as receiving the ACTION.VIEW intent from other apps in the AndroidManifest.xml. In the onResume() and onNewIntent() method of the DBRestoreLoaderActivity, we catch the intent and  set the Class of the intent to the activity we really want invoked, DBRestoreActivity.class.  We add the intent flags: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, and FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS, call startActivity(Intent) and finish() the DBRestoreLoaderActivity. This accomplished the behavior I was looking for.

I added FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS, because I noticed that the DBRestoreActivity was in the recent apps list, and even though I called finish() in the DBRestoreActivity immediately, and as the last method call, after calling startActivity(Intent), the activity was still in the recent list. For my application, I do not necessarily want the DBRestoreActivity listed in the recents list.

This appears to implement what I was looking for: a way to start my DBRestoreActivity within an existing task (if one exists) and clear the task list so that we don't have to worry about the user interacting with an activity that may be working with "dirty data". Obviously, you may want to prompt the user in the DBRestoreLoaderActivity and let them know that some action has occurred which required the current activity to be closed...

It seems to me, that if one was using ContentProvider and receiving notifications on data change, that one could just pop a message and let the user know that the data had changed. But this app is not using a ContentProvider, so it is not notified of changes to the underlying data.